# NSCoding, save image path instead of actual image

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
@property (strong) UIImage *thumbImage;
```

..

```
albumData *album1 = [[albumData alloc]initWithTitle:@"Eminem" style:@"123" thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpeg"]];
```

..

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    NSData *image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_thumbImage);
    [coder encodeObject:(image) forKey:@"thumbImageData"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    NSData *imgData = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbImageData"];
    _thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData ];
    return self;
}
```

Right now I'm using the above code to save data inside a plist file. How should I change the code in order to save just the image path \ name instead of saving the actual picture.

Comment: Do you have the path and name in ivars? You can't get that info from the `UIImage`.

Comment: I have the file name. I've updated the first post. Do I need a specific path? All the pics are in the app bundle.

Comment: You need at least the filename if you want to be able to use it to call `UIImage imageNamed:`. From the code you posted, all you have is a title and style inside the `albumData` class. You do not have a filename in `albumData`.

Comment: Oh I see, I only access the picture, not the file name. How do I save the file name then?

Comment: One option would be to pass in the filename instead of the image. Save the filename in an ivar like you do with the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file name, you can get its path using [-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3a), e.g.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"jpeg"];
```

As rmaddy said, you cannot get this from a UIImage, so you may have to get it and hang on to it when you create the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
@property (copy) NSString *thumbImage;
```

and save only image name instead of

```
@property (strong) UIImage *thumbImage;
```

then code/encode as string. When you need an image just write

```
[UIImage imageNamed:album1.thumbImage];
```

Another solution is to subclass UIImage class, add image path property, owerride UIImage's initialization methods to support saving path and override coder/encoder methods

**EDIT:**

Here is some example code:

UIImageWithPath.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImageWithPath : UIImage{
    NSString* filepath;
}

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString* filepath;

-(id)initWithImageFilePath:(NSString*) path;
@end
```

UIImageWithPath.m

```
#import "UIImageWithPath.h"

@implementation UIImageWithPath
@synthesize filepath;

-(id)initWithImageFilePath:(NSString*) path{
    self = [super initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if(self){
        [filepath release];
        filepath = [path copy];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [filepath release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Sample using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    img = [[UIImageWithPath alloc] initWithImageFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pause" ofType:@"png"]];
    iv.image = img;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"image file path %@", img.filepath);
}
```

So now your code/encode methods should look like this:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    NSString *path = _thumbImage.filepath;
    [coder encodeObject:(path) forKey:@"thumbImageData"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    NSString *path = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbImageData"];
    _thumbImage = [[UIImageWithPath alloc] initWithImageFilePath:path];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a full example of this code? I couldn't get the picture to load